# Reading JSON data from a streaming URL?

Tags: java, url, streaming

I am trying to consume JSON data from a streaming URL

The code snippet is as follows

```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

   if(response.getEntity().isStreaming() ){
     while (true) {
       BufferedHttpEntity _entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
       InputStream _stream = _entity.getContent();
       JSONObject _interaction = new JSONObject(_stream.toString());
       System.out.println(_interaction.toString());
    }
}
```

Please guide me on consuming this without any external libs

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "consuming this"?

Comment: *consume - Read and manipulate the data from the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it using Buffered Reader

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        if(response.getEntity().isStreaming() ){
                HttpEntity _entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_entity.getContent(),"utf-8"),8);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println( line.toString());
                }
                _entity.getContent().close();                   
        }
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataContractJsonSerializer check here for more info :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the example in Pure **Java**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "without external library" because it's kind of difficult to do without.

The google module gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is quite easy to use:

```
String jsonString = "your json string";
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourClass obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourClass.class);
```